# Echo PHP variable in JavaScript (and display value in iframe)

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I want to query a value from mysql with php, assign the value to a variable, echo the php variable in some JavaScript and have the value be displayed in an iframe.

I just can't get it to work...

**My PHP:**

```
<?php
$text_id = $_GET['text'];

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $text_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $text = $row['text'];
}
?>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
(The function is called with <body onLoad="iFrameOn();">)
function iFrameOn()
{
    richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
    window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($text); ?>;
}
```

Comment: put quotes around the the php echo: `= '<?php echo json_encode($text); ?>';`

Comment: That did not solve the problem I'm afraid. I've also tried displaying the variable with document.write('<?php echo json_encode($text); ?>') but that didn't work so it does not appear (so far at least) to be a problem with displaying the value in the iframe.

Comment: does it work in the main document (so not the iframe)?

Comment: Have you verified that your PHP is outputting something?  If it isn't, then the script may be outputting the result; however, the result is NULL.

Comment: I solved the problem. I had the file saved as .js, and of course in order to use php the file must be .php. Sorry for the stupid mistake and thank you very much for all of your answers.

Comment: @Riketh - add this as an answer and accept it to indicate this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had the file saved as .js, and of course in order to use php the file must be .php. Sorry for the stupid mistake and thank you very much for all of your answers.